# how to export current app users from mongo realm application?

Tags: mongodb, realm, mongodb-atlas

My question is a simple query regarding mongo realm application. How can we export the current app users from mongo realm application.

1. I am trying to clone an existing mongo realm application
2. I have successfully exported the mongo atlas db dump as well as the mongo realm application
3. I have successfully created new mongo realm application and imported all the previous existing setup
4. I am able to see the users collection in my mongo altas collection but when trying to login with there cred it shows user not exists
5. Please also note I am using default authentication i.e., "Email/Password"

Comment: The question is a bit vague. Are you asking about the actual Realm Authenticated Users or a Users collection you've created in your app? In other words, when I log into my Realm Consule and look in 'Collections' I don't see a Users collection (other than one that matches a Users Model in our app).

Comment: As I read your question it is about the Realm app users. Actually, I also want to know how to do this so I have just posted the question in the mongodb developer forum. You might want to watch for answers as well:

https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/how-to-export-realm-app-users/98617